# mvn eclipse:eclipse doesn't download other dependencies in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven

When I run the same command (mvn eclipse:eclipse) in Windows, it gets all the sub-dependencies of the dependency jars. While in Mac, it doesn't get them. Using the same pom.xml file.

Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_43, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, you will need to set this up in your `settings.xml`. What's the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: No, I'm not using a proxy on either machine. It's just when I run the mvn eclipse:eclipse in my Mac and refresh my Eclipse project, those sub-depency jars are shown in the reference libraries. But when I run the same mvn command in Windows and refresh my Eclipse project, the sub-dependency jars are shown in the reference libraries.